# serverless-offline-sqs : sls offline stuck on "offline: Starting Offline SQS: local/us-east-1." #171

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

sls offline command stuck on "offline: Starting Offline SQS: local/us-east-1."

```
"serverless-offline": "^6.8.0",
"serverless-offline-sqs": "4.0.0", //  and the all newest
```

```
serverless-offline-sqs:
skipCacheInvalidation: false
autoCreate: true
endpoint: http://0.0.0.0:9324
region: ${self:provider.region}
accessKeyId: root
secretAccessKey: root
```

What is the last working version of serverless-offline and serverless-offline-sqs ?

Answer (score 6):

This is an issue posted on their github: https://github.com/CoorpAcademy/serverless-plugins/issues/171

Basically you have to set NODE_ENV to "test". At least that is what they suggested and what I did.

Comment: Thanks, this issue had been created by me =)

Comment: Can anybody please guide me to this? I'm still not able to run sqs offline @MaxVinogradov